# Autowiring Class<T> for any T

Tags: java, spring

So, I have some generic components that use reflection to initialize themselves and by doing so, they require `Class<T>` objects at instanciation time. Those components use annotations in order to generate useful metadata and/or convert the object to another representation more appropriate for the task at hand.

I reduced my issue down to this sample component :

```
@Component
public class Instantiator<T> {
    final Class<T> klass;

    @Autowired
    public Instantiator(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    public T instantiate() {
        try {
            return klass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException|IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Spring does not know how to automatically inject `Class<T>` instances, so I tried writing the following boilerplate code for each `T` for which I want `Class<T>` to be available.

```
@Bean
Class<Instantiatee> instantiateeClass() {
    return Instanciatee.class;
}
```

It does not work.

Spring since version 4 has support for Autowiring generic types, but in my case, it has to infer what `T` is assigned to in `Class<T>`. Since by default Spring creates singleton beans and therefore could not possibly infer an appropriate `T`, I tried adding `@Scope("prototype")` but I ended up with a `ClassCastException` since the container does not know how to infer `T` anyway.

So, I removed the `@Component` annotation from Instantiator and settled on this workaround for each `T` I have :

```
@Bean
Instantiator<Instantiatee> instantiator() {
    return new Instantiator<>(Instantiatee.class);
}
```

Do you know a workaround to make this work so that `T` will be inferred each time I want an `Instantiator` or another generic component depending on it ?

FYI, we are using spring 4.1.4 with boot.

---

I posted a more complete sample there : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79e1a7ebe7c25c00a6c2.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. How and where will you use this singleton `Instanciator` bean? Please post a complete stacktrace of the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, I was not able to reproduce it (but I also don't know what you tried).

Comment: By the way, the English verb is spelled "instantiate", not "instanciate" (your code may be in a different language but you are also using it in your question)

Comment: This whole design sounds questionable, but I think you'll need qualifiers to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Defining beans with `@Bean`, you give the bean name in the method name by default - in your case `getInstanciateeClass`. Also, when autowiring the default bean name is considered the parameter name, in your case `klass`. Because of this, Spring cannot match the beans, since they have different names and most probably there are more than one `Class` instances in the `ApplicationContext`. It does not matter if one is `Class<Foo>` and another one is `Class<Bar>`, Spring sees them as `Class` so it cannot do autowiring by type.

You can fix this by using the same default name both when defining the bean and when autowiring it.

```
@Autowired
public Instanciator(Class<T> klass) {
    this.klass = klass;
}

@Bean
Class<Instanciatee> klass() {
    return Instanciatee.class;
}
```

You can also specify the name of the bean in the @Bean annotation:

```
@Autowired
public Instanciator(Class<T> klass) {
    this.klass = klass;
}

@Bean(name = "klass")
Class<Instanciatee> getInstanciateeClass() {
    return Instanciatee.class;
}
```

Or you can also give the bean name when autowiring:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getInstanciateeClass")
public Instanciator(Class<T> klass) {
    this.klass = klass;
}

@Bean
Class<Instanciatee> getInstanciateeClass() {
    return Instanciatee.class;
}
```

Comment: This means the design I had in mind, where the T could be changed in (Instanciator<A>, Instanciator<B>...) is not achievable with spring. I guess I'll have to go for a factory then.

Thanks !

Comment: I found out your answer is inaccurate as of spring 4.1: There is some support for wiring generic components. The problem lies in the fact that the `Instanciator` class uses the type parameter `T` in `Class<T>`. When requesting `Instanciator<FooBar>`, the bean factory is unaware that `T` equates to `FooBar`, so it likely interprets this the same way it would interpred a wildcard, and it will pick any `Class` object no matter its actual complete type.